# Java Hibernate получить значение и посчитать повторения

Tags: java, hibernate, map

Java Hibernate получить значение и посчитать повторения
Помогите пож-та есть таблица в базе данных, допустим в ней один столбец со значениями:

```
10
20
20
20
30
30
```

Мне нужно запросом к БД получить значение и кол-во повторений этого значения. И эти данные положить в Map

```
Map<Integer, Integer> states = new HashMap<>();
```

в Map нужно положить

```
Ключ 10, значение 1
Ключ 20, значение 3
Ключ 30, значение 2
```

Comment: В чем вопрос то? SQL нужен?

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу так

```
   Query query = em.createQuery(
                "SELECT e.campaignYandexId, COUNT(e) FROM GroupData e GROUP BY e.campaignYandexId");
        List<Object[]> resultList = query.getResultList();
        resultList.forEach(r -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r)));
```